# Как лучше всего скрыть не нужные поля?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Доброго времени суток. Поля сайта пополняются через API перебором массива через цикл foreach.
Напротив каждого поля есть кнопка "удалить". Суть кнопки скрыть не нужный контент, чтобы была возможность работать с остальным контентов - необходимо чтобы по нажатию "удалить" поле скрывалось, подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего это как реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?
foreach($b['response'] as $value) :
if (!$value['text']) continue;
$text = strip_tags ($value['text']); 
extract(str_parse(strip_tags($value['text'])));
?>
  <div class="horisontal-container">
         <div class="full-block-1">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<? echo  explode(".", $text_clean)[0] ?>" size="48">
            <div class="photo"> 
                <? for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {  ?> 
               <img class="img_content" style="background-image: url(<?= $value['attachments'][$i]['photo']['src_big']?>);">
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="full-block-2">
            <textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><? echo  $text_clean; ?></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="vertical-container">
            <div class="row-item-1"><input type="text" name="name" value="<? echo user($value['signer_id']) ?>" size="30"> </div>
            <div class="row-item-2"><input type="text" name="id" value="vk.com/id<?= strip_tags ($value['signer_id']); ?>" size="30"></div>
            <div class="row-item-2"><input type="text" name="phone" value="<? echo $phone ?>" size="30"> </div>
            <div class="row-item-2"><input type="text" name="price" value="<? echo $price ?>" size="30"> </div>
            <select class="row-item-2">
               <option>Город</option>
            </select>
            <select class="row-item-2">
               <option>Категория</option>
            </select>
            <select class="row-item-2">
               <option>Подкатегория</option>
            </select>
            <select class="row-item-2">
               <option>Подкатегория</option>
            </select>
            <select class="row-item-2">
               <option>Подкатегория</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="vertical-container buttom-block">
            <a href="#" class="buttom">Отправить</a>
            <a href="#" class="buttom-delete">Удалить</a>
         </div>
         <hr align="center" width="95%" size="1" color="grey" />
      </div>
<?php

endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @Elena, jq, может лучше https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: @qwabra чем лучше?

Comment: тем что нативный js и не нужно подключать jquery

Comment: @yolosora, 1. стоит метка "javascript" а не "jq" 2. есть кнопка, на кнопке висит функция. тк строки (контейнеры) генерируются динамически - значит есть переменная где они (контейнеры) хранятся при создании, вот эта переменная и используется в той самой функции на кнопке. удаляемый объект может не иметь ни id ни class

Comment: Тут нужно уточнение, нужно удаление, или же как в вопросе сказано "скрывалось" - что скорее всего реализуется через css.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Удаление не обязательно, можно и скрыть. Главное чтобы div контейнер исчез.

Comment: @Дмитрий определитесь что нужно, напишете так, чтобы мы поняли что вам Нужно, и тогда будет ответ на вопрос

Comment: @Дмитрий, ах, да, если используется JavaScript-фреймворк - напишете его название, метку с названием этого фреймворка прикрепите

Comment: @qwabra разве нельзя просто сделать `$(obj)` где `obj` - хранимый контейнер? Имхо слово "лучше" все таки не совсем корректное, решение с jq либо подходит либо нет (если требуется сугубо нативный js), если подходит, то что нативный js, что с jquery поверх - те же яйца только в иной инсталляции.

Comment: @qwabra  Обновил информацию, написал подробно что мне нужно

Comment: Народ, тут вообще php...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function deleteRow(el) {
  el.closest(".horisontal-container").remove();

  /* или так если хотите не удалить а скрыть */
  //el.closest(".horisontal-container").style.display = "none";

  return false;
}
```

```css
.horisontal-container {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="horisontal-container">
  элемент 1

  <div class="vertical-container buttom-block">
    <a href="#" class="buttom">Отправить</a>
    <a href="#" class="buttom-delete" onclick="return deleteRow(this)">Удалить</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="horisontal-container">
  элемент 2

  <div class="vertical-container buttom-block">
    <a href="#" class="buttom">Отправить</a>
    <a href="#" class="buttom-delete" onclick="return deleteRow(this)">Удалить</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="horisontal-container">
  элемент 3

  <div class="vertical-container buttom-block">
    <a href="#" class="buttom">Отправить</a>
    <a href="#" class="buttom-delete" onclick="return deleteRow(this)">Удалить</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно!

Comment: Internet Explorer&Safari не поддерживаются https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest @Дмитрий не спешите

Comment: @qwabra Сафари поддерживает, а IE, да не поддерживает, не вижу в этом проблемы. https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest

Comment: @qwabra Если нужна поддержка IE используйте полифил, он в статье что вы привели в ссылке, там даже несколько вариантов

Comment: @qwabra Проект делаю для себя, пользуюсь исключительно хромом. Спасибо